# Correct use of UNION in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to compute the difference between two different rating averages, one for rating of movies before a specific year_cutoff (1980) and the second one after year_cutoff, querying from two different databases, Rating and Movies.

What I did is:

I need to compute the difference of the average stars between the movies pre-1980 and post-1980.

At first I GROUPED BY movie titles and compute the rating average for each group.

Secondly, I divided these groups into two categories, pre-1980 and post-1980

Finally, I am trying to recompute the average (of the average) for each of these two groups, namely avgBefore and avgAfter and compute the difference of this two new averages

I expect one number that is the avgBefore - avgAfter (avgB - avgA)

Below is my attempt for the code. My main problem is to insert correctly the two conditions 'before' and 'after' 1980. I am trying to define aliases like avgB and avgA, but apparently the UNION clause is not properly called.

```
SELECT AVG(avgB) - AVG(avgA)
FROM(
SELECT AVG(stars) as avgB
FROM Rating
JOIN Movie
ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
GROUP BY title
HAVING year < 1980
UNION
SELECT AVG(stars) as avgA
FROM Rating
JOIN Movie
ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
GROUP BY title
HAVING year > 1980
);
```

Comment: What about `WHERE year < 1980` for the first and `WHERE year >= 1980` for the second?

Comment: If I set WHERE before each GROUP BY I get error Query failed to execute: near 'GROUP': syntax error

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Comment: You are not "querying from two different databases", but from two *tables* (that are in the same database). When working with multiple tables, you should qualify all columns. I suppose that `AVG(stars)` is `AVG(rating.stars)` and `year < 1980` is `movie.year < 1980`? So you want to know the rating difference between pre-1980 movies and post-1980 movies. (You are omitting all movies of 1980 itself, by the way, which may or may not be on purpose).

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. 

I need to compute the difference of the average stars between the movies pre-1980 and post-1980. 

At first I GROUPED BY movie title and compute the average for each group.

Secondly, I have to divide them into two categories, pre-1980 and post-1980

Finally, recompute the average (of the average) for each these two groups, namely avgBefore and avgAfter and compute the difference of this two new averages

Comment: As to your query: `UNION` and the more often used `UNION ALL` glue two queries together. These queries must select the same columns in regards of position and type. The final result gets its column names from the first query. So after applying `UNION` you have one or two rows (depending on whether the avarage values are the same or not) and the column is called avgB; there is no avgA anymore.

Comment: Hm, after reading your new comment: So this is not about pre- and post-1980 movies, but pre- and post-1980 comments on the same movie? (Is `year` a column in `movie` or `rating`?)

Comment: year is a column form movie, each movie has an assigned year

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have updated the original question explaining this

Comment: Okay, I hope I've got it now :-) I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the average rating per movie first. From this result you want to get the average movie rating both pre-1980 and post-1980. Two steps hence: an aggregation per movie, then a total aggregation.

```
select
  avg(r.stars) as total,
  avg(case when m.year < 1980 then r.stars end) as pre1980,
  avg(case when m.year > 1980 then r.stars end) as post1980,
  avg(case when m.year < 1980 then r.stars end) -
  avg(case when m.year > 1980 then r.stars end) as diff
from
(
  select mid, avg(stars) as stars
  from rating
  group by mid
) r
join movie m on m.mid = r.mid;
```

(As already mentioned, you may want to include 1980 movies in either the pre or the post range and not omit them completly.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettener  I get this error: Query failed to execute: near '(': syntax error

Comment: Oops, I missed the FROM keyword. Added it.

Comment: @ThrostenKettner Congratulations!! Successfully accomplished!. I got the correct result! Thanks so much! It was tricky for me! I should train more on the use of aliases like your definition of r.

Comment: @ThrostenKettner why did you need to create a mid column?

Comment: I didn't create anything. That's obviously the movie ID, present in both tables. In your original query you are using it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(avgB) - AVG(avgA)
  FROM(
       SELECT AVG(stars) as avgB
         FROM Rating
         JOIN Movie
         ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
        WHERE Movie.year < 1980
       GROUP BY title
      UNION
       SELECT AVG(stars) as avgA
         FROM Rating
         JOIN Movie
         ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
        WHERE Movie.year >= 1980
       GROUP BY title
      );
```

**NOTE**: I don't know where you get the `year` value from, so you will need to specify it.

**UPDATE**: fixed reference to `year`.

**UPDATE 2**: Corrected query.

Here is what I came up. Please note that I don't have access right now to a DB to verify syntax, but I guess it should be *mostly* OK:

```
SELECT (AVG(B.Rating_OLD) - AVG(B.Rating_NEW)) AS Rating_Diff
  FROM (
        SELECT A.title , AVG(A.stars_OLD) AS Rating_OLD ,AVG(A.stars_NEW) AS Rating_NEW
          FROM (
                SELECT title                                    , 
                       CASE 
                          WHEN Movie.year <  1980 THEN Rating.stars
                          ELSE                         0
                       END AS stars_OLD                         ,
                       CASE 
                          WHEN Movie.year >= 1980 THEN Rating.stars
                          ELSE                         0
                       END AS stars_NEW                         
                  FROM Rating
                  JOIN Movie
                   ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID
               ) A
         GROUP BY A.title 
       ) B
```

Comment: year comes from the Movie database

Comment: I guess, as commented above, UNION recognizes only one alias, avgB. More proper JOIN

Comment: `JOIN` will give you one record per title while `UNION` will give you 2, one from the OLD data and one from the NEW. Which one you need?

Comment: This code can't work because this script don't know what is avgA !

Comment: @Katusic you are right, but I'm not going to update the answer before I understand what the OP is looking for.

Comment: OK, got it. Will post an update to my answer later on (going to a meeting now). Just one clarification: Shouldn't you calculate the _WEIGHTED AVERAGES_. Imagine that you have 1000 votes for a movie before 1980 and only one vote after 1980. Unless you add weights, your result might be very misleading, wouldn't it?

Comment: @FDavidov in regard to weighted average, perhaps you are right, but for now I would like to fix errors in my code. My code doesn't work yet and cannot see the mistake. Many thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

What if we follow this approach:

```
SELECT 
    (AVG(CASE WHEN year < 1980 THEN stars ELSE 0 END)-
    AVG(CASE WHEN year >= 1980 THEN stars ELSE 0 END)) AS averag
FROM Rating
JOIN Movie ON Rating.mID = Movie.mID
```

Comment: This is exactly what you are trying to do from `UNION ALL` you wanna same output, aren't you ?

Comment: yes, the output is the difference of the averages, it is one number not the average of each grouped movie

Comment: Then we just need to remove `group by` which is not required in your case so try the updated one please.

Comment: I need to group by the titles and compute the average rate for each title. Subsequently I split pre- and post- 1980 and recompute the difference of the avgBefore and avgPost

Comment: I have update the original message explaining this detail. Thanks a lot for your efforts, it looks easy but for some reason cannot see the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use join instead on UNION:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(avgB) - AVG(avgA)
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT
            AVG(stars) as avgB
        FROM 
            Rating
        JOIN 
            Movie
        ON 
            Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
        WHERE 
            year < 1980
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            AVG(stars) as avgA
        FROM 
            Rating
        JOIN 
            Movie
        ON 
            Rating.mID = Movie.mID 
        WHERE 
            year < 1980
    ) t2
);
```

Comment: Than. I get this error : Query failed to execute: ambiguous column name: t1.mID. Actually neither to me is clear what is t1..after join it is t2?

Comment: sorry. That was a typo. `t1` and `t2` are just an alias for subquery

Comment: Change select to this: 
SELECT  t1.mID, AVG(t1.avgB) - AVG(t2.avgA)

Comment: Nope. Still get t1.mID = NULL and the difference accordingly

Comment: I have updated the query for single value i.e. removed group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way. You can't have two different aliases in UNION. Your script knows only about alias avgB.
Instead of UNION i suggest that you use JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

The  most efficient way to do this uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (AVG(CASE WHEN m.year < 1980 THEN r.stars END) -
        AVG(CASE WHEN m.year >= 1980 THEN r.stars END)
       ) AS averag
FROM Rating r JOIN
     Movie m
     ON r.mID = m.mID;
```

Trying to use two separate queries just makes the query more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still get 0.0 result. Originally it was suggested in the exercise "Make sure to calculate the average rating for each movie, then the average of those averages for movies before 1980 and movies after. Don't just calculate the overall average rating before and after 1980."